# Answer [Y/n] prompt from bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, prompt

I've seen other people write about this, but nothing has been working for me. I want to answer "yes" to a prompt from within a script when I go to remove a program. Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="This is where all the packages will be listed to install"

echo "What do you want to do?"
while true; do
    read -p "Enter: install, remove, or cancel: " yn
    case $yn in
        [install]* ) $a echo "ROS successfully uninstalled"; break;;
        [remove]* ) sudo apt-get remove ros-*; break;;
        [cancel]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "INVALID ANSWER!...";;
    esac

done
```

I read that the "expect" should work but it hasn't, unless I did something wrong. Any advice is appreciated!

George

Comment: Why do you have `$a` before the `echo` for the `install` case?

Comment: I have it there to make that section of the script look cleaner. I want it to perform whatever `$a` is and then `echo` that at the end

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't store code to execute in a variable. Define a shell function instead. `a () { code to install packages; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[]` around your case conditions, and you probably didn't want the `*` either:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="This is where all the packages will be listed to install"

echo "What do you want to do?"
while true; do
    read -p "Enter: install, remove, or cancel: " yn
    case $yn in
        install ) $a echo "ROS successfully uninstalled"; break;;
        remove ) sudo apt-get remove ros-*; break;;
        cancel ) exit;;
        * ) echo "INVALID ANSWER!...";;
    esac

done
```

The reason they use `[yY]*` in other scripts is because they want to match input with lowercase "y" or uppercase "y", followed by any characters, like "Y", "yes", "YES", etc.

Comment: so how would i add that in? under the remove command for example, when it goes to remove the program it prompts me for a yes or no command, so how do i make the script answer that question for me?

Comment: `apt-get` has a flag `--yes`.